# Is it safe to make the assumption that generic data column is not used by any other application for storing it own contact data

Tags: android

I am using the generic columns DATA1 to Data15 to store some data. My question is whether it is safe to assume that these columns are not being used by other android applications to store their own data. IF not how would I make sure that a particular column is not being used by any other application?

```
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValue(Data.DATA10,"Data")
```

Retrive data:

```
ContentResolver cr=context.getContentResolver();
Cursor emailCur = cr.query( 
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                ContactsContract.Data._ID + " = ?", 
                new String[]{str_id}, null); 
                while (emailCur.moveToNext()) 
       { 
                String name=emailCur.getString(
                          emailCur.getColumnIndex(Data.DATA10));

       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be safe, if you use your own MIME type value for the [MIMETYPE column](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.DataColumns.html#MIMETYPE). When querying the data table, a MIME is specified to query for specific results (Phone numbers, names, addresses and so on), so if you use a value special for your application, other applications will probably not use it/change it.

Read more about the data table [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html).

**EDIT:** Append this call to the `ContentProviderOperation` creation chain:

```
.withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, "yourCustomMimeType")
```

Comment: I edited the question to show how I am adding the data values. Could you please show me how to add the MIMETYPE? Also should the MIMETYPE be my own custom MIMETYPE or some standard defined in the CommomDataKinds? Alos what I was trying to ask is wheteher some other application will use DATA10 to store the data? IF they do and specify a different mimetype from mine wont it stilll overwrite the existing value and mimetype

Comment: Use your own MIMETYPE, and other application won't try to access/modify the values in the rows with this type.

Comment: That in turn brings me to the next question. I added how I am retrieving the data and there is no mimetype in it. Should there be a mimetype beacuse I get correct results even without it. And I can get the data so  other applications can too ,or am I mistaken here?

Comment: Other application can, too. But you should be filtering results by adding a WHERE clause to your selection query: `Data.MIMETYPE + " = 'yourCustomType'"`. Other application shouldn't be modifying these values (If they don't know/use the MIME type).

Comment: Okay. I guess I did not add the filter. Thats why I got confused. So I assume that all applications add a filter. Also while updating the contact information we use `.withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, "yourCustomMimeType").withValue(Data.DATA10,"Data")`. Will this not overwrite the value of DATA10 even if the Mimetypes are different?

Comment: True, it won't change any columns where the MIMETYPE is different from your custom one.